# How to properly check the HTTP response code in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class

I am writing a gem that will serve as a REST API client for the service my company provides.

For that, I have a `Channel` class that will serve as a means of interacting with the `/channels` path of the API. It uses [`HTTParty`](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) for the actual HTTP calls. This class has a method called create, that POSTs a Channel instance with the required attributes.

This is what the method looks like:

```
def create
  body = { external_id: external_id,
           name:        name,
           description: description }
  action = post "/", body
  case action.response.class
  when Net::HTTPAccepted      then return action
  when Net::HTTPNotAcceptable then raise HTTPNotAcceptable
  else raise "Server responded with " + Net::HTTPResponse::CODE_TO_OBJ[action.response.code].to_s
  end
end
```

The `post` method is an abstraction that transforms the body hash into JSON and attaches authentication and other attributes to the actual `HTTParty` call.

This does not work. Even when the response is a `202`, this `case` statement always falls on the `else` condition. I have attached a `pry` session after the `post` call to verify that the response was correct:

```
    38: def create
    39:   body = { external_id: external_id,
    40:            name:        name,
    41:            description: description }
    42:   action = post "/", body
 => 43:   case action.response.class
    44:   when Net::HTTPAccepted      then return action
    45:   when Net::HTTPNotAcceptable then raise HTTPNotAcceptable
    46:   else raise "Server responded with " + Net::HTTPResponse::CODE_TO_OBJ[action.response.code].to_s
    47:   end
    48: end

[1] (pry) #<ZynkApi::Channel>: 0> action.response.class
=> Net::HTTPAccepted
```

But it still falls on `else`:

```
[1] (pry) #<ZynkApi::Channel>: 0> action.response.class
=> Net::HTTPAccepted
[2] (pry) #<ZynkApi::Channel>: 0> n

From: /Users/cassiano/projects/Zynk/src/zynk_api/lib/zynk_api/channel.rb @ line 38 ZynkApi::Channel#create:

    38: def create
    39:   body = { external_id: external_id,
    40:            name:        name,
    41:            description: description }
    42:   action = post "/", body
    43:   case action.response.class
    44:   when Net::HTTPAccepted      then return action
    45:   when Net::HTTPNotAcceptable then raise HTTPNotAcceptable
 => 46:   else raise "Server responded with " + Net::HTTPResponse::CODE_TO_OBJ[action.response.code].to_s
    47:   end
    48: end
```

Comment: replace `case action.response.class` with `case action.response`, because class of class is a Class.

Comment: Thanks, @taro. This works, but I'm still puzzled.. `action.response.class == Net::HTTPAccepted` returns `true`, while `action.response == Net::HTTPAccepted` returns `false`. What sort of comparison is `case .. when` doing, if not `==`?

Comment: Case statement uses `===` operator, not `==`. You can read about that, for instance in this article: http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/how-a-ruby-case-statement-works-and-what-you-can-do-with-it/

Comment: @taro Make it an answer!

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Thanks for the edits. It makes more sense this way! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about case statement like it uses `===` method:

```
if Net::HTTPAccepted === action.response.class
  puts 'accepted'
elsif Net::HTTPNotAcceptable === action.response.class
  puts 'not acceptable'
else
  puts 'unknown status'
end
```

But, as you know - class of most classes is a Class, so you should rewrite your case like this (without calling class method on response):

```
case action.response
  when Net::HTTPAccepted
    return action
  when Net::HTTPNotAcceptable
    raise HTTPNotAcceptable
  else
    raise "Server responded with " + Net::HTTPResponse::CODE_TO_OBJ[action.response.code].to_s
end
```